# Will BoilerplateJS support latest RequireJS

Tags: requirejs, boilerplatejs

[enter link description here](http://boilerplatejs.org)BoilerplateJS only come with old 1.0.X RequireJS. Is it able to work with the latest one?

Comment: it is a best practice to give a feedback to someone who has answered your question. Also mark the answers as accepted, if it has helped you to resolve your issue!

Comment: thanks for the confirmation, i will have a try

Comment: so did it work? yeah, you should mark answer if it was correct ;)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It does work with the new RequireJS versions.

Replace the requirejs and the plugin files (text, domReady and i18n) in the libs folder. The order plugin is not needed. The path plugin is a custom plugin for BoilerplateJS and it works fine with the new versions.

Comment: I've updated the [repository](https://github.com/ectechno/boilerplatejs/) with the latest requirejs version